# google cloud messaging push with parse and android client does not work

Tags: parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

**used those lines in android:**

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = null;


 token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

**got exception , token=null.**

google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)

any suggestions?

checked that sender id is ok and api key. no clue.

thanks

Comment: Were you able to set up all the things in the prior steps mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)?

Answer (score 3):

I had this error as well. That was because I called instanceID.getToken in the main thread. The [GCD guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) says that: **Do not call this method in the main thread; instead, use a service that extends IntentService**.

[Here](https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/android-journal/gcm/) there is a tutorial where is shown how create an IntentService where you can call instanceID.getToken. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

thankx for the answer.
I did all the steps except the steps

sendRegistrationToServer(token);
....

since my token was null I was not able to procseed.
I had no problems with parse push service.
when I tried to replace it with gcm it did not work.

Comment: Were there any errors thrown on this line: `String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);`? Did you change the value of R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId to the project number?

Comment: no, I checked it by printing and seems to be in order.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you move the google-services.json file to your /app directory?

Comment: Yes its is their folder .I'm also using emulator "Andy". maybe it has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most definitely concerning your google-services.json file. Make sure that you have configured it correctly.

One of the reasons for this "unknown source" issue is a tampered file.